# How do I compile box model addition of browsers(firefox, chrome and safari) to another css file using scss?

Tags: css, sass, cross-browser, webkit

This is my scss code for default settings of css.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I have included in my main.scss file and the file names are correct.

```
@import "./resets";
@import "./variables";
```

However, it does not appear on my main.css file as it suppose to.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I am using VS code for this project and I tried to save all files but it did not work. The main.css file did not show the box sizing for browsers (firefox, chrome, safari).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `_` to the beginning of the file names, for example, `_variables.scss`.

Comment: Could you mark the question as answered?